# \listings code style for HTML5 (CSS, HTML, JavaScript)

Tags: formatting, listings, html, code, javascript

I would like to create a code style for HTML5 that can be used with the `\listings` package.

An HTML5 document consists of three languages: CSS, HTML and JavaScript. That makes the whole thing a bit more complicated, because one can only define a keyword field for three languages.

I oriented myself on the style of the NetBeans IDE ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjpdQ.png)).
I have come very far. Nevertheless, there are some problems ...

[image]

**Bug #1** 
The keyword `canvas` occurs both as an HTML tag and a variable. I want the HTML tag to be blue but not the JavaScript variable within the `<script>` block.

**Bug #2** 
Because I make blue slashes for the ending HTML tags, the forward slashes in my JavaScript texts also get blue.

**Missing Feature #3** 
Identifiers (#square, .box) in the CSS code are not green.

Can anyone help me to solve these problems? I don't want to use `\minted` because I've got already a lot of code with `\listings` in my documents.

I have also created a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{color}
    \definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.95}
    \definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{0.4, 0.4, 0.4}
    \definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.65, 0.12, 0.82}
    \definecolor{ocherCode}{rgb}{1, 0.5, 0} % #FF7F00 -> rgb(239, 169, 0)
    \definecolor{blueCode}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.93} % #0000EE -> rgb(0, 0, 238)
    \definecolor{greenCode}{rgb}{0, 0.6, 0} % #009900 -> rgb(0, 153, 0) 
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{listings}
\makeatletter
\lstdefinelanguage{HTML5}{
    sensitive=true,
    keywords={%
    % JavaScript
    typeof, new, true, false, catch, function, return, null, catch, switch, var, if, in, while, do, else, case, break,
    % HTML
    html, title, meta, style, head, body, script, canvas,
    % CSS
    border:, transform:, -moz-transform:, transition-duration:, transition-property:,
    transition-timing-function:
    },
    % http://texblog.org/tag/otherkeywords/
    otherkeywords={<, >, \/},   
    ndkeywords={class, export, boolean, throw, implements, import, this},   
    comment=[l]{//},
    % morecomment=[s][keywordstyle]{<}{>},  
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    morecomment=[s]{<!}{>},
    morestring=[b]',
    morestring=[b]",    
    alsoletter={-},
    alsodigit={:}
}
\lstset{%
    % Basic design
    backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
    basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},   
    frame=l,
    % Line numbers
    xleftmargin={0.75cm},
    numbers=left,
    stepnumber=1,
    firstnumber=1,
    numberfirstline=true,
    % Code design
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    ndkeywordstyle=\color{greenCode}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{ocherCode}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{darkgray}\ttfamily,
    % Code
    language={HTML5},
    tabsize=2,
    showtabs=false,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    extendedchars=true,
    breaklines=true
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Canvas-Rotation</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
      #square {
        border: 1px solid black;
                transform: scale(10) rotate(3deg) translateX(0px);
                -moz-transform: scale(10) rotate(3deg) translateX(0px);
      }

            .box {              
                transition-duration: 2s;
                transition-property: transform;
                transition-timing-function: linear;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="square" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = 200;
            canvas.height = 200;

            var image = new Image();
            image.src = 'images/card.png';
            image.width = 114;
            image.height = 158;
            image.onload = window.setInterval(function() {
                rotation();
            }, 1000/60);
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

I know that the task is pretty tough! But maybe we can do that collectively?

An HTML5 code formatting could be used universally.

P.S. I have read that there are commands like `usekeywordsintag` and `tagstyle`. But everytime I want to use them I get the error:

```
! Package keyval Error: tagstyle undefined.
```

Comment: You can only use `usekeywordsintag` if you use `language=html` somewhere in your `\lstdefinelanguage`. From the `listings` manual, page 28, "The package either use the first order keywords in tags or prints all identifiers inside `<>` in keyword style."

Comment: I think that the cleanest way would be to switch the language on keywords `style` and `script`. However, `listings` don't seem to provide such an option. (And neither could I discover a way to hack it in.) I think that this would be a nice feature to have (given that the mixture of languages in a single file or code chunk is becoming more and more common). Maybe you could put forth a feature request to the author/maintainer of `listings`?

Comment: This is an attempt to create a javaScript listing for ES6, Node.js, Express.js, Jasmine etc. into: https://github.com/xgirma/latex-javaScript

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Update: I am still improving the code style. You can find the latest version here:**
https://www.writelatex.com/74567mmxwkw - **I appreciate anyone who is testing :)**

**If you want to get a copy of the source code, you can get it here:** https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74217418/stackexchange/tex/html5_listings_sample.tex

After much trial and error and the help of people here from the community I have come to a very attractive result.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

The code is pretty intense, but it works. It would be nice if others could try it. Thus it is ensured that there are no errors. Unfortunately, all HTML elements and attributes, and CSS properties have to be entered manually. **Maybe we can put together a list of all these items?**

Together with the W3C specification it should be possible.

**Here is the code:**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{editorGray}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.95}
\definecolor{editorOcher}{rgb}{1, 0.5, 0} % #FF7F00 -> rgb(239, 169, 0)
\definecolor{editorGreen}{rgb}{0, 0.5, 0} % #007C00 -> rgb(0, 124, 0)
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
  morekeywords={typeof, new, true, false, catch, function, return, null, catch, switch, var, if, in, while, do, else, case, break},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  morecomment=[l]//,
  morestring=[b]",
  morestring=[b]'
}

\lstdefinelanguage{HTML5}{
        language=html,
        sensitive=true, 
        alsoletter={<>=-},
        otherkeywords={
        % HTML tags
        <html>, <head>, <title>, </title>, <meta, />, </head>, <body>,
        <canvas, \/canvas>, <script>, </script>, </body>, </html>, <!, html>, <style>, </style>, ><
        },  
        ndkeywords={
        % General
        =,
        % HTML attributes
        charset=, id=, width=, height=,
        % CSS properties
        border:, transform:, -moz-transform:, transition-duration:, transition-property:, transition-timing-function:
        },  
        morecomment=[s]{<!--}{-->},
        tag=[s]
}

\lstset{%
    % Basic design
    backgroundcolor=\color{editorGray},
    basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},   
    frame=l,
    % Line numbers
    xleftmargin={0.75cm},
    numbers=left,
    stepnumber=1,
    firstnumber=1,
    numberfirstline=true,
    % Code design   
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    commentstyle=\color{darkgray}\ttfamily,
    ndkeywordstyle=\color{editorGreen}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{editorOcher},
    % Code
    language=HTML5,
    alsolanguage=JavaScript,
    alsodigit={.:;},
    tabsize=2,
    showtabs=false,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    extendedchars=true,
    breaklines=true,        
    % Support for German umlauts
    literate=%
    {Ö}{{\"O}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1
    {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {ß}{{\ss}}1
    {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {ä}{{\"a}}1
    {ö}{{\"o}}1
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Canvas</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
      #square {
        border: 1px solid black;
                transform: scale(10) rotate(3deg) translateX(0px);
                -moz-transform: scale(10) rotate(3deg) translateX(0px);
      }

            .box {              
                transition-duration: 2s;
                transition-property: transform;
                transition-timing-function: linear;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="square" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = 200;
            canvas.height = 200;

            var image = new Image();
            image.src = 'images/card.png';
            image.width = 114;
            image.height = 158;
            image.onload = window.setInterval(function() {
                rotation();
            }, 1000/60);
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the rendering of `<` in the html tag. It's black while the rest are blue. But nevertheless, great work! +1

Comment: Thanks for the info! I fixed it. You can find the updated version here: http://www.writelatex.com/74567mmxwkw

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore, it points to a file without proper definitions.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it. Maybe someone has overwritten it. I will check if I have a backup.

Comment: I restored the last working version. You can also get a backup copy here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74217418/stackexchange/tex/html5_listings_sample.tex

Answer (score 14):

I too think this is a great idea!

As you suggested fetching the html tags and attributes from documentation, I went to the MDN page and found out they have all that info in a single html page. Based on [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99709/how-to-define-html-keywords-in-listings) by you, I've applied the same structure to all the tags, and it does work. Took me a while to realize that the order I was declaring each tag mattered, but a quick sorting fixed the issue. I repeated the process with the attributes too, so those two should be complete. For the CSS, however, I used a previous work I found somewhere else some days ago, so I'm not that sure.

Here's the code [you posted at writelatex.com](https://www.writelatex.com/74567mmxwkw) with all that data in place:

```
    \documentclass{scrreprt}
    \usepackage{color}
    \definecolor{editorGray}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.95}
    \definecolor{editorOcher}{rgb}{1, 0.5, 0} % #FF7F00 -> rgb(239, 169, 0)
    \definecolor{editorGreen}{rgb}{0, 0.5, 0} % #007C00 -> rgb(0, 124, 0)
    \usepackage{upquote}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
      morekeywords={break, case, catch, continue, debugger, default, delete,         do, else, false, finally, for, function, if, in, instanceof, new, null, return, switch, this, throw, true, try, typeof, var, void, while, with},
      morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
      morecomment=[l]//,
      morestring=[b]",
      morestring=[b]'
    }
    \lstdefinelanguage{CSS}{
      keywords={accelerator,azimuth,background,background-attachment,
            background-color,background-image,background-position,
            background-position-x,background-position-y,background-repeat,
            behavior,border,border-bottom,border-bottom-color,
            border-bottom-style,border-bottom-width,border-collapse,
            border-color,border-left,border-left-color,border-left-style,
            border-left-width,border-right,border-right-color,
            border-right-style,border-right-width,border-spacing,
            border-style,border-top,border-top-color,border-top-style,
            border-top-width,border-width,bottom,caption-side,clear,
            clip,color,content,counter-increment,counter-reset,cue,
            cue-after,cue-before,cursor,direction,display,elevation,
            empty-cells,filter,float,font,font-family,font-size,
            font-size-adjust,font-stretch,font-style,font-variant,
            font-weight,height,ime-mode,include-source,
            layer-background-color,layer-background-image,layout-flow,
            layout-grid,layout-grid-char,layout-grid-char-spacing,
            layout-grid-line,layout-grid-mode,layout-grid-type,left,
            letter-spacing,line-break,line-height,list-style,
            list-style-image,list-style-position,list-style-type,margin,
            margin-bottom,margin-left,margin-right,margin-top,
            marker-offset,marks,max-height,max-width,min-height,
            min-width,-moz-binding,-moz-border-radius,
            -moz-border-radius-topleft,-moz-border-radius-topright,
            -moz-border-radius-bottomright,-moz-border-radius-bottomleft,
            -moz-border-top-colors,-moz-border-right-colors,
            -moz-border-bottom-colors,-moz-border-left-colors,-moz-opacity,
            -moz-outline,-moz-outline-color,-moz-outline-style,
            -moz-outline-width,-moz-user-focus,-moz-user-input,
            -moz-user-modify,-moz-user-select,orphans,outline,
            outline-color,outline-style,outline-width,overflow,
            overflow-X,overflow-Y,padding,padding-bottom,padding-left,
            padding-right,padding-top,page,page-break-after,
            page-break-before,page-break-inside,pause,pause-after,
            pause-before,pitch,pitch-range,play-during,position,quotes,
            -replace,richness,right,ruby-align,ruby-overhang,
            ruby-position,-set-link-source,size,speak,speak-header,
            speak-numeral,speak-punctuation,speech-rate,stress,
            scrollbar-arrow-color,scrollbar-base-color,
            scrollbar-dark-shadow-color,scrollbar-face-color,
            scrollbar-highlight-color,scrollbar-shadow-color,
            scrollbar-3d-light-color,scrollbar-track-color,table-layout,
            text-align,text-align-last,text-decoration,text-indent,
            text-justify,text-overflow,text-shadow,text-transform,
            text-autospace,text-kashida-space,text-underline-position,top,
            unicode-bidi,-use-link-source,vertical-align,visibility,
            voice-family,volume,white-space,widows,width,word-break,
            word-spacing,word-wrap,writing-mode,z-index,zoom},  
      sensitive=true,
      morecomment=[l]{//},
      morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
      morestring=[b]',
      morestring=[b]",
      alsoletter={:},
      alsodigit={-}
    }
    \lstdefinelanguage{HTML5}{
            language=html,
            sensitive=true, 
            alsoletter={<>=-},
            otherkeywords={
            % HTML tags
            <, </, >,
            </a, <a, </a>,
            </abbr, <abbr, </abbr>,
            </address, <address, </address>,
            </area, <area, </area>,
            </area, <area, </area>,
            </article, <article, </article>,
            </aside, <aside, </aside>,
            </audio, <audio, </audio>,
            </audio, <audio, </audio>,
            </b, <b, </b>,
            </base, <base, </base>,
            </bdi, <bdi, </bdi>,
            </bdo, <bdo, </bdo>,
            </blockquote, <blockquote, </blockquote>,
            </body, <body, </body>,
            </br, <br, </br>,
            </button, <button, </button>,
            </canvas, <canvas, </canvas>,
            </caption, <caption, </caption>,
            </cite, <cite, </cite>,
            </code, <code, </code>,
            </col, <col, </col>,
            </colgroup, <colgroup, </colgroup>,
            </data, <data, </data>,
            </datalist, <datalist, </datalist>,
            </dd, <dd, </dd>,
            </del, <del, </del>,
            </details, <details, </details>,
            </dfn, <dfn, </dfn>,
            </div, <div, </div>,
            </dl, <dl, </dl>,
            </dt, <dt, </dt>,
            </em, <em, </em>,
            </embed, <embed, </embed>,
            </fieldset, <fieldset, </fieldset>,
            </figcaption, <figcaption, </figcaption>,
            </figure, <figure, </figure>,
            </footer, <footer, </footer>,
            </form, <form, </form>,
            </h1, <h1, </h1>,
            </h2, <h2, </h2>,
            </h3, <h3, </h3>,
            </h4, <h4, </h4>,
            </h5, <h5, </h5>,
            </h6, <h6, </h6>,
            </head, <head, </head>,
            </header, <header, </header>,
            </hr, <hr, </hr>,
            </html, <html, </html>,
            </i, <i, </i>,
            </iframe, <iframe, </iframe>,
            </img, <img, </img>,
            </input, <input, </input>,
            </ins, <ins, </ins>,
            </kbd, <kbd, </kbd>,
            </keygen, <keygen, </keygen>,
            </label, <label, </label>,
            </legend, <legend, </legend>,
            </li, <li, </li>,
            </link, <link, </link>,
            </main, <main, </main>,
            </map, <map, </map>,
            </mark, <mark, </mark>,
            </math, <math, </math>,
            </menu, <menu, </menu>,
            </menuitem, <menuitem, </menuitem>,
            </meta, <meta, </meta>,
            </meter, <meter, </meter>,
            </nav, <nav, </nav>,
            </noscript, <noscript, </noscript>,
            </object, <object, </object>,
            </ol, <ol, </ol>,
            </optgroup, <optgroup, </optgroup>,
            </option, <option, </option>,
            </output, <output, </output>,
            </p, <p, </p>,
            </param, <param, </param>,
            </pre, <pre, </pre>,
            </progress, <progress, </progress>,
            </q, <q, </q>,
            </rp, <rp, </rp>,
            </rt, <rt, </rt>,
            </ruby, <ruby, </ruby>,
            </s, <s, </s>,
            </samp, <samp, </samp>,
            </script, <script, </script>,
            </section, <section, </section>,
            </select, <select, </select>,
            </small, <small, </small>,
            </source, <source, </source>,
            </span, <span, </span>,
            </strong, <strong, </strong>,
            </style, <style, </style>,
            </summary, <summary, </summary>,
            </sup, <sup, </sup>,
            </svg, <svg, </svg>,
            </table, <table, </table>,
            </tbody, <tbody, </tbody>,
            </td, <td, </td>,
            </template, <template, </template>,
            </textarea, <textarea, </textarea>,
            </tfoot, <tfoot, </tfoot>,
            </th, <th, </th>,
            </thead, <thead, </thead>,
            </time, <time, </time>,
            </title, <title, </title>,
            </tr, <tr, </tr>,
            </track, <track, </track>,
            </u, <u, </u>,
            </ul, <ul, </ul>,
            </var, <var, </var>,
            </video, <video, </video>,
            </wbr, <wbr, </wbr>,
            />, <!
            },  
            ndkeywords={
            % General
            =,
            % HTML attributes
            accept=, accept-charset=, accesskey=, action=, align=, alt=, async=, autocomplete=, autofocus=, autoplay=, autosave=, bgcolor=, border=, buffered=, challenge=, charset=, checked=, cite=, class=, code=, codebase=, color=, cols=, colspan=, content=, contenteditable=, contextmenu=, controls=, coords=, data=, datetime=, default=, defer=, dir=, dirname=, disabled=, download=, draggable=, dropzone=, enctype=, for=, form=, formaction=, headers=, height=, hidden=, high=, href=, hreflang=, http-equiv=, icon=, id=, ismap=, itemprop=, keytype=, kind=, label=, lang=, language=, list=, loop=, low=, manifest=, max=, maxlength=, media=, method=, min=, multiple=, name=, novalidate=, open=, optimum=, pattern=, ping=, placeholder=, poster=, preload=, pubdate=, radiogroup=, readonly=, rel=, required=, reversed=, rows=, rowspan=, sandbox=, scope=, scoped=, seamless=, selected=, shape=, size=, sizes=, span=, spellcheck=, src=, srcdoc=, srclang=, start=, step=, style=, summary=, tabindex=, target=, title=, type=, usemap=, value=, width=, wrap=,
            % CSS properties
            accelerator:,azimuth:,background:,background-attachment:,
            background-color:,background-image:,background-position:,
            background-position-x:,background-position-y:,background-repeat:,
            behavior:,border:,border-bottom:,border-bottom-color:,
            border-bottom-style:,border-bottom-width:,border-collapse:,
            border-color:,border-left:,border-left-color:,border-left-style:,
            border-left-width:,border-right:,border-right-color:,
            border-right-style:,border-right-width:,border-spacing:,
            border-style:,border-top:,border-top-color:,border-top-style:,
            border-top-width:,border-width:,bottom:,caption-side:,clear:,
            clip:,color:,content:,counter-increment:,counter-reset:,cue:,
            cue-after:,cue-before:,cursor:,direction:,display:,elevation:,
            empty-cells:,filter:,float:,font:,font-family:,font-size:,
            font-size-adjust:,font-stretch:,font-style:,font-variant:,
            font-weight:,height:,ime-mode:,include-source:,
            layer-background-color:,layer-background-image:,layout-flow:,
            layout-grid:,layout-grid-char:,layout-grid-char-spacing:,
            layout-grid-line:,layout-grid-mode:,layout-grid-type:,left:,
            letter-spacing:,line-break:,line-height:,list-style:,
            list-style-image:,list-style-position:,list-style-type:,margin:,
            margin-bottom:,margin-left:,margin-right:,margin-top:,
            marker-offset:,marks:,max-height:,max-width:,min-height:,
            min-width:,transition-duration:,transition-property:,
            transition-timing-function:,transform:,
            -moz-transform:,-moz-binding:,-moz-border-radius:,
            -moz-border-radius-topleft:,-moz-border-radius-topright:,
            -moz-border-radius-bottomright:,-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:,
            -moz-border-top-colors:,-moz-border-right-colors:,
            -moz-border-bottom-colors:,-moz-border-left-colors:,-moz-opacity:,
            -moz-outline:,-moz-outline-color:,-moz-outline-style:,
            -moz-outline-width:,-moz-user-focus:,-moz-user-input:,
            -moz-user-modify:,-moz-user-select:,orphans:,outline:,
            outline-color:,outline-style:,outline-width:,overflow:,
            overflow-X:,overflow-Y:,padding:,padding-bottom:,padding-left:,
            padding-right:,padding-top:,page:,page-break-after:,
            page-break-before:,page-break-inside:,pause:,pause-after:,
            pause-before:,pitch:,pitch-range:,play-during:,position:,quotes:,
            -replace:,richness:,right:,ruby-align:,ruby-overhang:,
            ruby-position:,-set-link-source:,size:,speak:,speak-header:,
            speak-numeral:,speak-punctuation:,speech-rate:,stress:,
            scrollbar-arrow-color:,scrollbar-base-color:,
            scrollbar-dark-shadow-color:,scrollbar-face-color:,
            scrollbar-highlight-color:,scrollbar-shadow-color:,
            scrollbar-3d-light-color:,scrollbar-track-color:,table-layout:,
            text-align:,text-align-last:,text-decoration:,text-indent:,
            text-justify:,text-overflow:,text-shadow:,text-transform:,
            text-autospace:,text-kashida-space:,text-underline-position:,top:,
            unicode-bidi:,-use-link-source:,vertical-align:,visibility:,
            voice-family:,volume:,white-space:,widows:,width:,word-break:,
            word-spacing:,word-wrap:,writing-mode:,z-index:,zoom:
            },  
            morecomment=[s]{<!--}{-->},
            tag=[s]
    }

    \lstset{%
        % Basic design
        backgroundcolor=\color{editorGray},
        basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},   
        frame=l,
        % Line numbers
        xleftmargin={0.75cm},
        numbers=left,
        stepnumber=1,
        firstnumber=1,
        numberfirstline=true,
        % Code design   
        keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
        commentstyle=\color{darkgray}\ttfamily,
        ndkeywordstyle=\color{editorGreen}\bfseries,
        stringstyle=\color{editorOcher},
        % Code
        language=HTML5,
        alsodigit={.:;},
        tabsize=2,
        showtabs=false,
        showspaces=false,
        showstringspaces=false,
        extendedchars=true,
        breaklines=true,        
    }
    \begin{document}
        \begin{lstlisting}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Canvas</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <style>
          #square {
            border: 1px solid black;
                    transform: scale(10) rotate(3deg) translateX(0px);
                    -moz-transform: scale(10) rotate(3deg) translateX(0px);
          }

                .box {              
                    transition-duration: 2s;
                    transition-property: transform;
                    transition-timing-function: linear;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <canvas id="square" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
        <script>
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                canvas.width = 200;
                canvas.height = 200;

                var image = new Image();
                image.src = 'images/card.png';
                image.width = 114;
                image.height = 158;
                image.onload = window.setInterval(function() {
                    rotation();
                }, 1000/60);
       </script>
      </body>
    </html>
        \end{lstlisting}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer and welcome to tex.se! Do you have an idea what causes the strange indentation of the first lines?

Comment: I am pleased to see that the work on that listing goes on. Great! Keep it up! We also have to find a way to do proper highlighting for HTML Comments because at the moment the beginning and ending is colored but not the rest which looks a bit weird. Anyway. Good work!!

Comment: why after the fourth row left edge is different?

Comment: Is there a way to make everything after `:` but before `;` in a different color than black?

Comment: There's another good example of HTML formatting at https://github.com/PKief/latex-thesis-template/blob/master/settings/listings.tex . It doesn't seem to suffer from the indentation issue. I imagine it's some difference in configuration and probably the ultimate solution would merge both.

Comment: @Daniel The strange indentation is caused by the `<, </, >,` tags defined in `otherkeywords`. I'm unsure why.