# How to use alsolanguage in \listings package?

Tags: formatting, listings

I defined keywords for the JavaScript programming language and HTML.

I have read that it is possible to use the keywords of both languages in a `\listings` code snippet. But in my example, the JavaScript keywords are not shown in blue.

[image]

Here is my code example. Is my use of `alsolanguage` incorrect?

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{listings}
\makeatletter
\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
  keywords={var, function}
}

\lstdefinelanguage{HTML5}{
    language=HTML,
    sensitive=true,
    tagstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    usekeywordsintag=true
}

\lstset{%
    % Basic design
    basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
    % Code design   
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    % Code
    language=HTML5,
    tabsize=2,
    showtabs=false,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    extendedchars=true,
    breaklines=true
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=HTML5,alsolanguage=JavaScript]
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Canvas-Rotation</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="square" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = 200;
            canvas.height = 200;

            var image = new Image();
            image.src = 'images/card.png';
            image.width = 114;
            image.height = 158;
            image.onload = window.setInterval(function() {
                rotation();
            }, 1000/60);
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JavaScript language is loaded, but because of how the html language is defined in `listings` the content inside `<script>` is formatted as text. It is controlled by the key `tag`. I don't know exactly what it does, but by making HTML5 inherit everything from HTML and overwriting the `tag` it seems to work for this simple example.

When using more than one language just must use the key `morekeywords` for JavaScript or else it will overwrite the list of keywords for HTML.
Furthermore `alsolanguages` doesn't switch between the two languages but simply unifies the two languages. So when I define canvas as a keyword for HTML5, the variable canvas inside the JavaScript is also still formated as keyword.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
  morekeywords={var, function},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},%
  morecomment=[l]//,%
  morestring=[b]",%
  morestring=[b]'%
}

\lstdefinelanguage{HTML5}[]{HTML}{
    sensitive=false,
    morekeywords={canvas},
    tag=[s]
}

\lstset{%
    % Basic design
    basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
    % Code design   
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    % Code
    language=HTML5,
    tabsize=2,
    showtabs=false,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    extendedchars=true,
    breaklines=true
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=HTML5,alsolanguage=JavaScript]
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Canvas-Rotation</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="square" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = 200;
            canvas.height = 200;

            var image = new Image();
            image.src = 'images/card.png';
            image.width = 114;
            image.height = 158;
            image.onload = window.setInterval(function() {
                rotation();
            }, 1000/60);
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input! This sample was made to help with this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99500/listings-code-style-for-html5-css-html-javascript - Your code gave me light into the darkness. Too bad that the JavaScript code is formatted too. I'm still looking for a solution to combine CSS, JavaScript and HTML code.... :/

Comment: Is it maybe possible to specify <canvas for morekeywords? Because then the canvas in JavaScript won't be highlighted anymore. I tried it with morekeywords={<canvas} but it didn't work. :(