# How to define HTML keywords in \listings

Tags: formatting, listings, html

I'm working on the implementation of a [HTML5 code style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99500/listings-code-style-for-html5-css-html-javascript) for `\listings`.

Currently I have the problem that there are different ways to define HTML tags. In my example, I don't get `/p` in `<p></p>` marked.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**My keyword definition looks like this:**

```
otherkeywords={>,><,</p,<p,</p>}
```

If I add `/p` to the list, then `</p>` is not marked anymore.

**Here is my language definition:**

```
\lstdefinelanguage{HTML5}{
  language=html,
  sensitive=true,   
  alsoletter={<>=-},    
  morecomment=[s]{<!-}{-->},
  tag=[s],
  otherkeywords={>,><,</p,<p,</p>}
}
```

For a complete example I've created this document: 
https://www.writelatex.com/74567mmxwkw

Comment: Shouldn't it work if you omit `><` from the keyword list?

Comment: Wow. That was easy. I missed the forest for the trees. Thank you! You can write this as a solution, so that I can check off the question.

Comment: @cgnieder Please write a short answer (or cast the first closing vote).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're declaring the keyword `><` which leads to the wrong coloring. The line

```
<p></p>
```

is interpreted as the keywords `<p` and `><` followed by `/p` (which is *no* keyword) and then again a keyword, `>`.

Leaving the `><` keyword out should suffice. The line the would be interpreted as the keywords `<p`, `>`, `</p`, and `>`, which should be what you want.