# How to correctly use equal sign in keywords for listings?

Tags: listings, keywords

I work on a [listings code style for HTML5](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99500/listings-code-style-for-html5-css-html-javascript/). The style looks quite good but I have a little problem with the equals sign. I defined the equals sign as a keyword:

```
 ndkeywords={=, ... }
```

This will cause the equals sign to appear in green (which is what I want). However, in `+=` the `=` is also green (but not the `+`).

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Can I define that the equals sign is only highlighted when there is a space before?

Here is the code example: https://www.writelatex.com/74567mmxwkw

Comment: Could you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. The linked code is quite much and contains a lot that isn’t even related to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have simply forgotten to declare `+` as a letter for `html`.  Adding `+` to `alsoletter` as below

```
\lstdefinelanguage{HTML5}{
  language=html,
  sensitive=true,   
  alsoletter={<>=-+},
  ...
```

gives your desired colouring

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.95}
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{0.4, 0.4, 0.4}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.65, 0.12, 0.82}
\definecolor{editorGray}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.95}
\definecolor{editorOcher}{rgb}{1, 0.5, 0} % #FF7F00 -> rgb(239, 169, 0)
\definecolor{editorGreen}{rgb}{0, 0.5, 0} % #007C00 -> rgb(0, 124, 0)
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{listings}
% CSS
\lstdefinelanguage{CSS}{
  keywords={color,background-image:,margin,padding,font,weight,display,position,top,left,right,bottom,list,style,border,size,white,space,min,width, transition:, transform:, transition-property, transition-duration, transition-timing-function}, 
  sensitive=true,
  morecomment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]",
  alsoletter={:},
  alsodigit={-}
}

% JavaScript
\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
  morekeywords={typeof, new, true, false, catch, function, return, null, catch, switch, var, if, in, while, do, else, case, break},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  morecomment=[l]//,
  morestring=[b]",
  morestring=[b]'
}

\lstdefinelanguage{HTML5}{
  language=html,
  sensitive=true,   
  alsoletter={<>=-+},   
  morecomment=[s]{<!-}{-->},
  tag=[s],
  otherkeywords={
  % General
  >,
  % Standard tags
    <!DOCTYPE,
  </html, <html, <head, <title, </title, <style, </style, <link, </head, <meta, />,
    % body
    </body, <body,
    % Divs
    </div, <div, </div>, 
    % Paragraphs
    </p, <p, </p>,
    % scripts
    </script, <script,
  % More tags...
  <canvas, /canvas>, <svg, <rect, <animateTransform, </rect>, </svg>, <video, <source, <iframe, </iframe>, </video>, <image, </image>
  },
  ndkeywords={=,
  % General
  +=,
  % HTML attributes
   charset=, src=, id=, width=, height=, style=, type=, rel=, href=,
  % SVG attributes
  fill=, attributeName=, begin=, dur=, from=, to=, poster=, controls=, x=, y=, repeatCount=, xlink:href=,
  % CSS properties
  margin:, padding:, background-image:, border:, top:, left:, position:, width:, height:,
    % CSS3 properties
  transform:, -moz-transform:, -webkit-transform:,
  animation:, -webkit-animation:,
  transition:,  transition-duration:, transition-property:, transition-timing-function:,
  },
}

\lstset{%
  % General design
  backgroundcolor=\color{editorGray},
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},   
  frame=l,
  % line-numbers
  xleftmargin={0.75cm},
  numbers=left,
  stepnumber=1,
  firstnumber=1,
  numberfirstline=true, 
  % Code design
  identifierstyle=\color{black},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
  ndkeywordstyle=\color{editorGreen}\bfseries,
  stringstyle=\color{editorOcher}\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\color{darkgray}\ttfamily,
  % Code
  language=HTML5,
  alsolanguage=JavaScript,
  alsodigit={.:;},  
  tabsize=2,
  showtabs=false,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  extendedchars=true,
  breaklines=true,
  % German umlauts
  literate=%
  {Ö}{{\"O}}1
  {Ä}{{\"A}}1
  {Ü}{{\"U}}1
  {ß}{{\ss}}1
  {ü}{{\"u}}1
  {ä}{{\"a}}1
  {ö}{{\"o}}1
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Listings Style Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
      /* CSS Test */
      * {
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Paragraphs are fine -->
    <div id="box">          
            <p>
              Hello World
            </p>
      <p>Hello World</p>
      <p id="test">Hello World</p>
            <p></p>
    </div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <!-- HTML script is not consistent -->
    <script src="js/benchmark.js"></script>
    <script>
      function createSquare(x, y) {
        // This is a comment.
        var square = document.createElement('div');
        square.style.width = square.style.height = '50px';
        square.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';

        /*
         * This is another comment.
         */
        square.style.position = 'absolute';
        square.style.left = x + 'px'; 
        square.style.top = y + 'px';

        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        body.appendChild(square);
      };

      // Please take a look at +=
      window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
        // German umlaut test: Berührungspunkt ermitteln
        var x = event.touches[0].pageX;
        var y = event.touches[0].pageY;
        var lookAtThis += 1;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

*Update* Having `>` as general keyword means the final `>` in a comment gets the wrong colour, as pointed out by @kexxcream.  A partial work around is to include `>` in each keyword as appropriate.  The listings code for `html` contains something rather more sophisticated to deal with this.

Comment: The second time that you saved me. Thank you!

Comment: There is one issue with your code. It gives a blue color for the ">" sign at the end of a comment marked with <!-- --> while the rest of the comment is grey.

Comment: @kexxcream Thanks for spotting that.  It is a different question to the one asked here, and is due to other parts of the code from the link solution.  However, I have now fixed it.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Unfortunately, now the end ">" of each tag has also changed color to black. Take for instance the tag `<html>` - it starts with a blue `<` and ends with a black `>`.

Comment: @kexxcream OK - I have rolled back my edit.  I think you should ask a separate question; this was not the issue I was answering in my solution above.

Comment: @AndrewSwann No worries, your solution is good but has to be complemented by writing out the actual tags, for instance `<html>` instead of `<html`.

Comment: @AndrewSwann It seems that adopting a tag solution like I suggested didn't work out quite well. I have posted a new question for this problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252307/specific-color-for-different-tags-and-comments-using-listings-package